# The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect?

Tags: spring, jquery, spring-mvc

I have a controller like follows

```
@Controller
public class SettingsController {
   @RequestMapping(value="/editname",method=RequestMethod.POST)
   public void editName(@RequestParam(value="firstname") String firstname,
                        @RequestParam(value="lastname") String lastname) {
      final Object principal = 
         SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
      try {
         jdbcPersonRepository.updateName(principal.toString(), firstname, lastname);
      } catch (SignInNotFoundException e) {
      }
    }
 }
```

and I have my ajax form submit.

```
 $(function() {
  //twitter bootstrap script
    $("button#submit").click(function(){
    var $form = $(this).closest("form");
    var type = $form.attr('method');
    $.ajax({
      type: $form.attr('method'),
      url: $form.attr('action'),
      data: $form.serialize(),
      dataType : "json",
        success: function(msg){
                $("#thanks").html(msg)
               $("#form-content").modal('hide');    
        },
        error: function(){
           //alert("failure");
        }
      });
});
});
```

and my twitter bootstrap model which has a form which triggers the ajax is as follows

```
  <!-- Name Edit div -->
<div id="form-content" class="modal hide fade in" tabindex="-1">
  <form name="edit-form" action="<c:url value="/editname" />" method="post">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <h4>Edit Name</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
     <div class="control-group">
        <div class="controls">
          <ul class="nav nav-list">
            <li class="nav-header">First Name</li>
            <li><input type="text" placeholder="First Name" name="firstName" id="firstName" class="input-xlarge help-inline"></li>
            <li class="nav-header">Last Name</li>
            <li><input type="text" placeholder="Last Name" name="lastName" id="lastName" class="input-xlarge help-inline"></li>
         </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
       <button id="submit"  class="btn btn-success">Update</button>
       <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" >Close</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Does any anybody have a clue regarding this error.
?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the method declaration, the `@RequestMapping` annotations give the parameter names as `firstname` and `lastname`.  In the form HTML they are `firstName` and `lastName`.

Request parameter names are case sensitive ... ergo, they don't match, and Spring tells you this is an invalid request because mandatory parameters are missing.